# Why are goblins bad for war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Everyone says not to use goblins for war and I just need a breakdown as to why that is.

Comment: Most people already mentioned why they are bad... but they can be good as well. I don't usually use them, but I occasionally do when I know exactly what they will do: for instance, goblins will trigger traps and won't be affected by them if they just keep going through: yes, even spring traps. Now if there's a particular area you know is riddled with traps and there's a resource building at the end of that area, what better place to put a few goblins to clear all of them before your main army comes in? :)

Answer (score 7):

In Clan Wars, [stars are everything.](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/5-quick-tips-clan-wars-clash-clans/)  That means you need to try and wipe their base, rather than just raid it for resources.  Remember that stars are only awarded for destruction of the town hall, and for 50% and 100% base destruction.

Goblins are good for raiding resources.  They hit collectors and storages for extra damage, but they are relatively weak otherwise.  Mortars make short work of them, and they can't really hit walls well enough to break through.

Most other troops either hit defenses or don't have a particular target they prefer.  This means that your goblins are likely to split off from the pack and attract the attention of other defenses.

Thus, goblins are bad for war because they're not aligned with the goals of war raids, they're weak, and they're prone to running off by themselves and getting splatted to death by mortars.

Comment: Plus, Collectors and mines are empty at the war base, thus attacking for resources over stars is pointless.

Comment: @Neffer_23, they're not completely empty, but it is a pretty meaningless amount of resources, generally.

Comment: cited from [Clash of Clans Wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ) "Your war base does not generate resources."

Comment: @Neffer_23, cited from [Supercell's CW FAQ](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ): `There is always a small amount of resources available in the storages of enemy War Bases.`  It's true that it's not generated by the war base, but it's there nonetheless.  Go watch a clan war replay, and you can see it there too.

Comment: I understand your point, but why waste troop space on gobs anyway?

Comment: @Neffer_23, oh, I'm not suggesting you should put goblins in your raid troops.  I said in the answer that it's a *terrible* idea.  I was just pointing out that your assertion that there were no resources to be had was incorrect.  It's not enough to change the reasoning for not picking goblins, though.

Comment: okay. Makes sense now. I understand what you mean now

Answer (score 1):

Goblins aren't the best but they're certainly not bad.

Many players dislike them cause you won't get many trophies using them and in Clan Wars the major part is getting the stars! But in some cases, they are definitely neat and strategical in small amounts for accumulating resources (which isn't that important).

Goblins are also the fastest troop in the game, and are also great at destroying resource vessels. They deal double damage to: (Gold Mines, Elixir Collectors and storages for each)

But despite being good at taking resources, they lack at pretty much everything else and the main goal of getting stars, and that's why they're disliked by people.

Answer (score 1):

Using goblins isn't about collecting resources, it's about using the goblin's attack strategy to your advantage. There are many special needs situations that goblins can fill, but they require advanced strategic thought and execution. It's not for everyone. If you're just going to spam goblins in a War, don't bother. If you want to use them to trigger big bombs and spring traps, practice a lot. If you want to use a couple for diversionary tactics, practice a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised people say goblins are bad for war, those who say this, probably are not a good player or donot know the perfect combination of troops

1. goblins are best for raiding resources but a strategy should be applied
2. they should be left all out , only when all of the splash damages like, mortars or wiz towers are taken out.
3. before that you can use barchers army take the defenses out, the thing that makes goblins awesome is that they are smart, unlike barbs archers or even giants they find the actual target that we are heading for.
4. a combination of 4 giants, 8 wall breakers, 44 goblins, 60 archers, and 60 barbarian is the troop i have been using since about an year for now, works superfine

Answer (score 0):

Goblins can be use to attract other defenses to destroy your goals. For instance, you can use it to distract mortars so that other units can come near it.

However, Goblins can only be of use if you have a great strategy. Although goblins lack many things they have some things that others don't have.

I like goblins and use it on every attack so take your own risk when using them.

Answer (score 0):

goblins can be really usefull but I really dont know why coc players do not use them.They have many qualities that other troop do not have. They can become more powerful with combinations. We can use them to fail the traps,to attract the defencens,to take out the resourses fast and many other things and its up to all coc players that what they whant to do.

I have also resarched about some combinations like:
5 to8 goblins, 1to2 gaints
(this combination helps to break the walls fast as every coc player keeps his resources insinde the wall. Its a better idea because the wall breakers also hurts or kills the troops.)

Comment: This may be true, but doesn't really answer the question as to why _people think they are useless_. Once you get enough reputation, you should be able to post things like this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: What are you taking about

Comment: We are a Q&A-site. The (almost 2 years old) question is "Why are goblins bad for war?" I'm asking wether or not you are actually answering the question here.